# Pandas get year out of date column

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains a column named `start_year`.

It has a lot of styles written inside it and I need it to be written only by here.
For example:

| start_year in table | start_year as I need |
| --- | --- |
| 27 December 1949 | 1949 |
| 168 BC | -168 |
| Ongoing | 2021 (Today year) |
| 1902(Malvar surrender) 1913 (Irreconcilables active) | 1902 |
| 1903-1905 | 1903 |

I hope the table helps you understand my problem.

Answer (score 1):

try via `extract()` and `fillna()`:

```
val=df['start_year in table'].str.extract('(-?[0-9]+)').fillna('2021')

df['start_year as I need']=df['start_year in table'].str.extract('(\d{4})').fillna(val)
```

If `-` sign was not initially present in **'start_year as I need'** column where values is **BC** then you can use boolean masking after running the above code:

```
m=df['start_year in table'].str.contains('BC')

df.loc[m,'start_year as I need']='-'+df.loc[m,'start_year as I need']
```

Comment: Worked like magic execpt to the part where I have BC in here.. can you help me with that? I want BC year to become the same year with minus before like: 168 BC -> -168

Comment: Updated answer...Kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: Thanks! can you help me with one little thing more? 
For rows with date like this 27 December 1949 it keeps the 27 value

Comment: Updated answer...Kindly have a look **:)**